# Multihreading do I correctly use wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote a solution of philosophers problem. It is running and I get correct output on the console BUT the `println()` after `wait()` is never printed. Please tell me why. I pointed it out in the code.

The solution meant to be somehting *similar* to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Resource_hierarchy_solution

```
public class Philosopher extends Thread {
    String name;
    // boolean je, czeka;
    int nr;
    Fork left, right;

    public Philosopher(String name, int nr, Fork left, Fork right) {
        this.nr = nr;
        this.name = name;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        System.out.println("NR " + nr +"  "+ left + " " + right);
    }

    public void run() {
        // while(true){
        try {
            Fork minF = Fork.min(left, right);
            Fork maxF = Fork.max(left, right);

            synchronized (minF) {
                if (!minF.used) {
                    minF.used = true;
                    System.out.println("P" + nr + " took fork " + minF);
                } else {
                    minF.wait();
                    minF.used = true;
                    System.out.println("I waited and took fork " + minF); //why it is never PRINTEDDD???
                }
                synchronized (maxF) {
                    if (!maxF.used) {
                        maxF.used = true;
                        System.out.println("P" + nr + " took fork "
                                + maxF);
                    } else {
                        maxF.wait();
                        maxF.used = true;
                        System.out.println("I waited and took fork "+ maxF); //why it is never PRINTEDDD??
                    }
                    System.out.println("I am eating right now" + this);
                    eating();
                    System.out.println("P" + nr
                            + " I have eaten  I am giving back the forks");
                    minF.used = false;
                    System.out.println("P" + nr +  " NOTIFY fork" + minF);
                    minF.notify();
                    maxF.used = false;
                    System.out.println("P" + nr + " NOTIFY fork" + maxF);
                    maxF.notify();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // }
    }

    public void eating() throws InterruptedException {
        int time = (int) (Math.random() * 2000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("P" + nr + " " + i);
            Thread.sleep(time / 5);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Philosopher " + nr;
    }

    public static void startPhilosophers(Philosopher[] f) {
        for (int i = f.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            f[i].start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fork[] t = Fork.getArrayOfForks();
        Philosopher[] f = { new Philosopher("philosopher 1", 1, t[0], t[4]),
                new Philosopher("philosopher 2", 2, t[1], t[0]),
                new Philosopher("philosopher 3", 3, t[2], t[1]),
                new Philosopher("philosopher 4", 4, t[3], t[2]),
                new Philosopher("philosopher 5", 5, t[4], t[3]), };
        startPhilosophers(f);

    }

}
```

---

```
public class Fork {
    boolean used;
    int nr;

    public Fork(boolean used, int nr) {
        this.used = used;
        this.nr = nr;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "F" + nr;
    }
    public static Fork min(Fork l, Fork p){
        if(l.nr < p.nr)
            return l;
        return p;
    }


    public static Fork max(Fork l, Fork p){
        if(l.nr > p.nr)
            return l;
        return p;
    }
    public static Fork[] getArrayOfForks() {
        Fork[] t = new Fork[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
            t[i] = new Fork(false, (i + 1));
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

---

```
EXAMPLE output
NR 1  F1 F5
NR 2  F2 F1
NR 3  F3 F2
NR 4  F4 F3
NR 5  F5 F4
P5 took fork F4
P5 took fork F5
I am eating right nowPhilosopher 5
P4 took fork F3
P5 0
P2 took fork F1
P2 took fork F2
I am eating right nowPhilosopher 2
P2 0
P5 1
P2 1
P5 2
P2 2
P5 3
P2 3
P5 4
P2 4
P5 I have eaten  I am giving back the forks
P5 NOTIFY forkF4
P5 NOTIFY forkF5
P4 took fork F4
I am eating right nowPhilosopher 4
P4 0
P2 I have eaten  I am giving back the forks
P2 NOTIFY forkF1
P2 NOTIFY forkF2
P3 took fork F2
P1 took fork F1
P1 took fork F5
I am eating right nowPhilosopher 1
P1 0
P1 1
P4 1
P1 2
P4 2
P1 3
P4 3
P1 4
P4 4
P1 I have eaten  I am giving back the forks
P1 NOTIFY forkF1
P1 NOTIFY forkF5
P4 I have eaten  I am giving back the forks
P4 NOTIFY forkF3
P4 NOTIFY forkF4
P3 took fork F3
I am eating right nowPhilosopher 3
P3 0
P3 1
P3 2
P3 3
P3 4
P3 I have eaten  I am giving back the forks
P3 NOTIFY forkF2
P3 NOTIFY forkF3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flup already answered you question, but moving the synchronization blocks is not sufficient; if yu want to use your `used` flags together with `wait` and `notify`, you need to check the condition you are `wait`ing for in a loop, as `wait` may return even without `notify`.

One solution might be:

```
public class Demo
{

    public static class Philosopher
        extends Thread
    {

        String name;

        int nr;

        Fork left, right;


        public Philosopher( String name, int nr, Fork left, Fork right )
        {
            this.nr = nr;
            this.name = name;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            System.out.println( "NR " + nr + "  " + left + " " + right );
        }


        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // while ( true )
            try {
                Fork minF = Fork.min( left, right );
                Fork maxF = Fork.max( left, right );

                synchronized ( minF ) {
                    if ( ! minF.used ) {
                        minF.used = true;
                        System.out.println( "P" + nr + " took fork " + minF );
                    } else {
                        while ( minF.used )
                            // <- YOU NEED TO CHECK THIS IN A LOOP
                            minF.wait();
                        minF.used = true;
                        System.out.println( "I waited and took fork " + minF ); // why it is never PRINTEDDD???
                    }
                }
                synchronized ( maxF ) {
                    if ( ! maxF.used ) {
                        maxF.used = true;
                        System.out.println( "P" + nr + " took fork " + maxF );
                    } else {
                        while ( maxF.used )
                            // <- YOU NEED TO CHECK THIS IN A LOOP
                            maxF.wait();
                        maxF.used = true;
                        System.out.println( "I waited and took fork " + maxF ); // why it is never PRINTEDDD??
                    }
                }

                System.out.println( "I am eating right now" + this );
                eating();
                System.out.println( "P" + nr + " I have eaten  I am giving back the forks" );

                synchronized ( minF ) {
                    minF.used = false;
                    System.out.println( "P" + nr + " NOTIFY fork" + minF );
                    minF.notify();
                }

                synchronized ( maxF ) {
                    maxF.used = false;
                    System.out.println( "P" + nr + " NOTIFY fork" + maxF );
                    maxF.notify();
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                // ignore
            }
        }


        public void eating()
            throws InterruptedException
        {
            int time = (int) ( Math.random() * 2000 );

            for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {
                System.out.println( "P" + nr + " " + i );
                Thread.sleep( time / 5 );
            }
        }


        public String toString()
        {
            return "Philosopher " + nr;
        }


        public static void startPhilosophers( Philosopher[] f )
        {
            for ( int i = f.length - 1; i >= 0; i -- ) {
                f[ i ].start();
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Fork
    {

        boolean used;

        int nr;


        public Fork( boolean used, int nr )
        {
            this.used = used;
            this.nr = nr;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "F" + nr;
        }


        public static Fork min( Fork l, Fork p )
        {
            if ( l.nr < p.nr )
                return l;
            return p;
        }


        public static Fork max( Fork l, Fork p )
        {
            if ( l.nr > p.nr )
                return l;
            return p;
        }


        public static Fork[] getArrayOfForks()
        {
            Fork[] t = new Fork[ 5 ];
            for ( int i = 0; i < t.length; i ++ ) {
                t[ i ] = new Fork( false, ( i + 1 ) );
            }
            return t;
        }
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Fork[] t = Fork.getArrayOfForks();
        Philosopher[] f =
            { new Philosopher( "philosopher 1", 1, t[ 0 ], t[ 4 ] ), new Philosopher( "philosopher 2", 2, t[ 1 ], t[ 0 ] ),
                new Philosopher( "philosopher 3", 3, t[ 2 ], t[ 1 ] ), new Philosopher( "philosopher 4", 4, t[ 3 ], t[ 2 ] ),
                new Philosopher( "philosopher 5", 5, t[ 4 ], t[ 3 ] ), };
        Philosopher.startPhilosophers( f );
    }

}
```

However, be sure to understand that in this example, you are making things overcomplicated. As you have an order on the locks, you can get rid of `used` and simplify this:

```
public class Demo2
{

    public static class Philosopher
        extends Thread
    {

        String name;

        int nr;

        Fork left, right;


        public Philosopher( String name, int nr, Fork left, Fork right )
        {
            this.nr = nr;
            this.name = name;
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
            System.out.println( "NR " + nr + "  " + left + " " + right );
        }


        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // while ( true )
            try {
                Fork minF = Fork.min( left, right );
                Fork maxF = Fork.max( left, right );

                synchronized ( minF ) {
                    synchronized ( maxF ) {
                        System.out.println( "I am eating right now" + this );
                        eating();
                        System.out.println( "P" + nr + " I have eaten  I am giving back the forks" );
                    }
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                // ignore
            }
        }


        public void eating()
            throws InterruptedException
        {
            int time = (int) ( Math.random() * 2000 );

            for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {
                System.out.println( "P" + nr + " " + i );
                Thread.sleep( time / 5 );
            }
        }


        public String toString()
        {
            return "Philosopher " + nr;
        }


        public static void startPhilosophers( Philosopher[] f )
        {
            for ( int i = f.length - 1; i >= 0; i -- ) {
                f[ i ].start();
            }
        }

    }

    public static class Fork
    {

        int nr;


        public Fork( int nr )
        {
            this.nr = nr;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "F" + nr;
        }


        public static Fork min( Fork l, Fork p )
        {
            if ( l.nr < p.nr )
                return l;
            return p;
        }


        public static Fork max( Fork l, Fork p )
        {
            if ( l.nr > p.nr )
                return l;
            return p;
        }


        public static Fork[] getArrayOfForks()
        {
            Fork[] t = new Fork[ 5 ];
            for ( int i = 0; i < t.length; i ++ ) {
                t[ i ] = new Fork( i + 1 );
            }
            return t;
        }
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Fork[] t = Fork.getArrayOfForks();
        Philosopher[] f =
            { new Philosopher( "philosopher 1", 1, t[ 0 ], t[ 4 ] ), new Philosopher( "philosopher 2", 2, t[ 1 ], t[ 0 ] ),
                new Philosopher( "philosopher 3", 3, t[ 2 ], t[ 1 ] ), new Philosopher( "philosopher 4", 4, t[ 3 ], t[ 2 ] ),
                new Philosopher( "philosopher 5", 5, t[ 4 ], t[ 3 ] ), };
        Philosopher.startPhilosophers( f );
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use wait/notify but it's overly heavy for this use case. The second sample is exactly what I wrote, no?

Comment: The first solution was to show what needed to be fixed. I assumed the OP wanted to implement this to learn about threading. And yes, the second example is a full version of your answer, but your answer did not contain that code when I wrote it. (Carvets of parallel work without synchonisation ... :D)

Answer (score 2):

```
synchronized (minF) {
    if (!minF.used) { // always
        minF.used = true;
    }
    ...
    minF.used = false;
    minF.notify();
}
```

You're synchronizing on the forks so the philosopher already has a lock on them when he checks if they are in use.
The philosopher sets `fork.used` to true but sets it back to false before leaving the synchronized block and releasing the lock.

EDIT: as requested, updated version of the code. If you use synchronized blocks, which you already do, you need not do the administration yourself:

```
synchronized (minF) {
    synchronized (maxF) {
        System.out.println("I am eating right now" + this);
        eating();
        System.out.println("P" + nr
            + " I have eaten  I am giving back the forks");
    }
}
```

If you want to write it out explicitly, I'd make use of the `java.util.concurrent` classes and have Fork extend from [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Your code then looks like this:

The fork:

```
public class Fork extends Semaphore {
int nr;

public Fork(int nr) {
    super(1); // can be handed out to only one person at a time
    this.nr = nr;
}
...
```

And the Philosopher:

```
minF.acquire();
maxF.acquire();
System.out.println("I am eating right now" + this);
eating();
System.out.println("P" + nr
    + " I have eaten  I am giving back the forks");
maxF.release();
minF.release();
```

Comment: Could you please edit my code to show how it sould work? I thought that he has to set it to false before he notify other philosopher that the fork is free to use.

Comment: Could you please edit my code to show how it sould work? I thought that he has to set it to false before he notify other philosopher that the fork is free to use. If he does the other way it will notify that the fork is free to use but the Fork.used field will be TRUE not false.

Comment: The synchronized blocks do the work for you. I've added a simpler version of your code that I think will do the trick as well.

Comment: And added a version that uses explicit semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the Fork->used attribute is always initialized to false within the getArrayOfForks() method, so your if condition will always be executed where as the wait() is in the else condition on each synchronized block.

Comment: When for example P5 will take his right fork first the P4 will see that this fork(hist left) is used(used == true) so the else should be executed.